# Transform a one dimensional list to a multidimentional (parent/child) list based on element value

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm working with a piece of data and need to structure it into a parent/child kinda thing.

Here is the data I have. The title and content have been modified for the example. The level key is the main thing here as far as the data is concerned.

```json
[
    {
        "content": null,
        "level": 1,
        "number": null,
        "title": "Level 1 title"
    },
    {
        "content": null,
        "level": 2,
        "number": "1",
        "title": "Level 2 title (1)"
    },
    {
        "content": "Level 3 content (1.1)",
        "level": 3,
        "number": "(ހ)",
        "title": null
    },
    {
        "content": "Level 3 content (1.2)",
        "level": 3,
        "number": "(ހ)",
        "title": null
    },
    {
        "content": "Level 3 content (1.3)",
        "level": 3,
        "number": "(ނ)",
        "title": null
    },
    {
        "content": null,
        "level": 2,
        "number": "2",
        "title": "Level 2 title (2)"
    },
    {
        "content": "Level 3 content (2.1)",
        "level": 3,
        "number": "(ހ)",
        "title": null
    },
    {
        "content": "Level 3 content (2.2)",
        "level": 3,
        "number": "(ހ)",
        "title": null
    },
]
```

What I want to do is read through this list and end up with the following

```json
[
    {
        "content": null,
        "level": 1,
        "number": null,
        "title": "Level 1 title",
        "children": [
            {
                "content": null,
                "level": 2,
                "number": "1",
                "title": "Level 2 title (1)",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "content": "Level 3 content (1.1)",
                        "level": 3,
                        "number": "(ހ)",
                        "title": null
                    },
                    {
                        "content": "Level 3 content (1.2)",
                        "level": 3,
                        "number": "(ހ)",
                        "title": null
                    },
                    {
                        "content": "Level 3 content (1.3)",
                        "level": 3,
                        "number": "(ނ)",
                        "title": null
                    }
                ]
            },

            {
                "content": null,
                "level": 2,
                "number": "2",
                "title": "Level 2 title (2)",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "content": "Level 3 content (2.1)",
                        "level": 3,
                        "number": "(ހ)",
                        "title": null
                    },
                    {
                        "content": "Level 3 content (2.2)",
                        "level": 3,
                        "number": "(ހ)",
                        "title": null
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

#### What I've tried

I have tried to group all items where the level is the same and append it to the parent. But then I immediately get confused and come to a full stop.

Below is my attempt at it, while *trying* to keep track of the current and parent section levels and indexes.

```py
parent_section = None
parent_section_idx = 0
current_level = 0
next_level = 0

for i, section in enumerate(chunk):
    current_level = section.level

    if section.level == current_level:
        parent_section = section
        parent_section_idx = i

    if section.level == next_level:
        chunk[parent_section_idx].children.append(section)
        # parent_section.children.append(section)

    if section.level != current_level:
        next_level += 1
        parent_section = section
```

I couldn't find questions about this particular scenario. Most of the similar questions are going from multidimensional to one dimensional. Excuse me for my lack of research.

Comment: That JSON is not valid cause of the trailing comma on the second-last line. But either way, if you can successfully load it into Python, the JSON itself is irrelevant; just give us the Python data instead. You can [edit]. For reference, see [mre]. On that note, please simplify the data as well, for readability. It looks like the only relevant field is the level, so you could probably just remove all the other fields.

Comment: After trying it out for myself, I've confirmed the level is the only relevant field yeah, but it also helps a lot to have a unique value for each dict like those `1`, `1.1`, and `1.2` you have in yours.

Answer (score 1):

So I don't know exactly if that can help you, but here is a (ugly) example of what could kinda work for what you would wish to accomplish :

```
def imbricate(sections_list):
    index_at = 0

    def sub_imbricate(child_list, at_level):
        nonlocal index_at
        nonlocal sections_list

        while index_at < len(sections_list):
            section = sections_list[index_at]
            if section['level'] > at_level:
                if not 'children' in child_list[-1].keys():
                    child_list[-1]['children'] = []
                sub_imbricate(child_list[-1]['children'], section['level'])
            elif section['level'] == at_level:
                child_list.append(section.copy())
                index_at += 1
            elif section['level'] < at_level:
                return child_list

        return child_list

    return sub_imbricate([], 1)
```

It can be done better, and doesn't handle exceptions, but maybe can you get a better understanding of how to reach your objective from that snippet.

I have a bit of confusion as to whether or not there should be cases where two successive entry can have their "level" attribute differ by more than one.

Regardless you just need to recursively pass through the whole list by increasing or decreasing your "level" of imbrication, from what I can understand.

*Note : you probably already know but to test that JSON in python without unpacking it, you can just replace the null values with "None" and voilà theWholeThing = <copyPaste>*